# What is the Blue Star alert in the mini map?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I already checked the legends in the main map and there is no reference there.

Googling also returned nothing.
[image: bluestar]

So, what is that blue asterisk on the map?

Comment: I believe it indicates a police presence or a police-based dynamic mission (e.g. stopping crime in progress). I'll have to check in game and find one to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a random event that you could intervene in for street cred, should you choose.

[image]

It's not the same as reported crimes from the NCPD scanner events as there is usually a police presence already and you get rewarded for completing. This you just get the experience and loot from the enemies you stop.

Comment: I just stopped my bike on the way to a side mission to check it... just a group of thugs trying to get some money from a person :)